# Best way to decouple large size class

Tags: ios, architecture, swift3, protocols, decoupling

I have a singleton manager class that have around 4000+ line of code. I have to decouple this class. So i have a way to use extension and protocol to decouple this class, but i would like to know some other way to decoupling. Please suggest if any way possible.

Comment: You should post more information  for your trouble, just this we can not know how to help you.

Comment: You should probably read up on the different types of architecture patterns you could use and see which fits your needs best. Sample reference: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52

Comment: I found solution for it. I am going to use multiple inheritance & protocol to decouple large size class.